# fyne custom widget not refreshed

Tags: go, fyne

I'm trying to write a custom widget that responds to mouse events. Here is a very simple example

```golang
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/driver/desktop"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
    "image/color"
)

type TestWidget struct {
    widget.BaseWidget
    X float32
    Y float32
}

func NewTestWidget() *TestWidget {
    return &TestWidget{}
}

func (w *TestWidget) CreateRenderer() fyne.WidgetRenderer {
    return TestWidgetRenderer{w}
}

func (w *TestWidget) MinSize() fyne.Size {
    return fyne.NewSize(400, 200)
}

// MouseIn is a hook that is called if the mouse pointer enters the element.
func (w *TestWidget) MouseIn(event *desktop.MouseEvent) {

}

// MouseMoved is a hook that is called if the mouse pointer moved over the element.
func (w *TestWidget) MouseMoved(event *desktop.MouseEvent) {
    w.X, w.Y = event.Position.X, event.Position.Y
    w.Refresh()
}

// MouseOut is a hook that is called if the mouse pointer leaves the element.
func (w *TestWidget) MouseOut() {

}

type TestWidgetRenderer struct {
    w *TestWidget
}

// Destroy is for internal use.
func (r TestWidgetRenderer) Destroy() {
}

func (r TestWidgetRenderer) MinSize() fyne.Size {
    return fyne.Size{400, 200}
}

// Layout is a hook that is called if the widget needs to be laid out.
// This should never call Refresh.
func (r TestWidgetRenderer) Layout(size fyne.Size) {
}

// Objects returns all objects that should be drawn.
func (r TestWidgetRenderer) Objects() []fyne.CanvasObject {
    res := make([]fyne.CanvasObject, 0)
    res = append(res, &canvas.Line{
        Position1:   fyne.Position{0, 0},
        Position2:   fyne.Position{r.w.X, r.w.Y},
        Hidden:      false,
        StrokeColor: color.Black,
        StrokeWidth: 5,
    })
    return res
}

// Refresh is a hook that is called if the widget has updated and needs to be redrawn.
// This might trigger a Layout.
func (r TestWidgetRenderer) Refresh() {
}

func main() {
    adminApp := app.New()
    mainWindow := adminApp.NewWindow("")
    mainWindow.SetContent(container.New(layout.NewHBoxLayout(), NewTestWidget()))

    mainWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

This widget is supposed to draw a black line from the top left corner of the window to the position of the mouse pointer. In reality, it does not draw anything until I resize the window. In other words, the widget's X and Y fields are set, but it is not refreshed (not re-rendered). Even though I call `widget.Refresh()` from the `MouseMoved` event handler.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE** I just realized that when BaseWidget.Refresh() is called, it does nothing at all. I could catch this in the debugger:

[image]

The "impl" is always nil (I guess because the widget is not using any already existing widget?) and so renderer.Refresh() is never called.

I'm not sure what it means. Does it mean that it is not possible to write a custom widget that is not based on any existing widget?

Answer (score 0):

You have used BaseWidget, but didn’t call ExtendBaseWidget in your constructor.

Perhaps the docs here could be a little clearer https://docs.fyne.io/extend/custom-widget

Comment: Hello, I realized my mistake and called ExtendBaseWidget but it still does not work. It only refreshes the canvas when I resize the window.

Comment: Your renderer has an empty Layout and Refresh methods… so I guess it’s clear something is missing. Consider what your widget should do if it is resized or asked to refresh and fill in those blanks.

Comment: The renderer refresh method is empty, because I don't know how to refresh. Base widget.Refresh is not supposed to be called manually, right? How can I refresh (paint) on the canvas then?

Comment: The purpose of the refresh on a widget renderer is to update the child elements that are used to draw it. So you update their properties and call Refresh on those instances.

Comment: Just to be clear - your implementation of “Objects” returns a slice of objects that are never updated. This is a contributing factor to why they don’t update. The change you see is probably stacking more and more objects into the tree as “Objects()” creates more each draw

Comment: Are you suggesting that the renderer should keep a reference to those canvas objects, and set their properties wieh renderer.Refresh() is called? I have used many gui toolkits before, and I find fyne difficult to understand.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in fyne documentation that renderer.Objects() is additive, and that anything returned by Objects() will forever be drawn. It is anything but not clear. The official "creating a custom widget" documentation does not explain many key concepts.

Comment: A fair point. It is nonetheless true, and may help with your issue.